# Are all versions of the android support library given the same revision number?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I see that the current revision of the Android Support Library is 21.0.3:

[image: sdk manager screenshot]

Does that mean that the most recent revision of each version of the support library (v4, v7, v13, etc.) has a revision number of 21.0.3?

In other words if I want to update my `build.gradle` file to the latest revision, that each version will have that revision number?

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3' **
```

** I realized that I only need one of these in my build.gradle file. I'm just showing each to demonstrate my question.

EDIT: 
To clarify, I don't just mean right now with the current revision. I mean is this *always* the case with every revision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe this is always true. If you inspect the contents of the directory

`<path-to-sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/`

you can see the available versions of the support libraries (open each subdirectory to view the revision numbers). Mine are all maxed at 21.0.3 right now.